# Improving efficiency of a C loop

Tags: c, loops, optimization

I have some working c code that I am looking to make more efficient. I know that it is best to avoid if statements in loops however I am struggling to get around this here. Can anyone suggest how I could make the following code more efficient?

```
for(iy=0;iy<Ny;iy++) {
for(ix=0;ix<Nx;ix++) {


    if (ix==0) {
      pudx = (u[1][iy] + u[Nx-1][iy] - 2.0*u[0][iy])/(calc1);   
    } else if (ix==Nx-1) {
      pudx = (u[0][iy] + u[Nx-2][iy] - 2.0*u[Nx-1][iy])/(calc1);  
    } else {
      pudx = (u[ix+1][iy] + u[ix-1][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc1);
    }

    if (iy==0) {
      pudy = (u[ix][1] + u[ix][Ny-1] - 2.0*u[ix][0])/(calc2);    
    } else if (iy==Ny-1) {
      pudy = (u[ix][0] + u[ix][Ny-2] - 2.0*u[ix][Ny-1])/(calc2);   
    } else {
      pudy = (u[ix][iy+1] + u[ix][iy-1] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc2);
    }


    u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0*u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc*(pudx+pudy);

  }
}
```

I am aware that such optimization can be done with a compiler but I would like to improve the efficiency with the -o flag (no compiler optimization).

Comment: You _could_ go by optimising the comparisons out from the loops, but I suspect that even good compilers can do that. The costly parts in your code are the floating point operations. Good optimisations are often based on clever use of information on your data. Since we know nothing about that, there's little one can do better than an optimising compiler.

Comment: How large are Nx and Ny?

Comment: 512x512 - I would like to improve the loop efficiency using the -o flag, so without the compilers help.

Comment: Questions regarding the improvement of otherwise working code are better suited to [codereview.se], but be sure to follow their content guidelines.

Comment: Another thing you can do is take the reciprocal of `calc1` and `calc2` outside of the loop, then inside the loop replace the divides with multiplies.  The results probably won't be identical, but should be very close.

Comment: Your separate cases could be collapsed by applying modular arithmetic.  For example, the first `if` nest could be served by `pudx = (u[(ix+1) % Nx][iy] + u[(Nx+ix-1)%Nx][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc1);`.  This has no conditionals at all, but whether it in fact improves performance can only be determined by testing.

Comment: IMHO You dont need the middle case `} else if (ix==Nx-1) {
      pudx = (u[0][iy] + u[Nx-2][iy] - 2.0*u[Nx-1][iy])/(calc1);` since Nx-2 is inside the range, and Nx-1 is equal to ix, here. And you could take the edge cases out of the loops (or compute the adjusted indexes into temps, if you have enough registers)

Comment: Given the `if` statements involve the first and last loop iterations, just peel those off of the loop.

Comment: I don't see what was unclear about this question, (other than *why* the OP didn't want to use compiler optimizations.) It seems pretty straightforward to me: "what manual optimizations could I apply to make this code run faster in an environment where compiler optimizations are unavailable or otherwise not desired?"

Answer (score 2):

After @JohnBollinger: (untested, obviously)

---

```
unsigned ix, iy;
for(iy=0;iy<Ny;iy++) {
  unsigned  yl,yh;

  yl = (iy -1) %Ny; yh = (iy +1) %Ny;
  for(ix=0;ix<Nx;ix++) {
      unsigned xl,xh;

      xl = (ix -1) %Nx; xh = (ix +1) %Nx;
      yl = (iy -1) %Ny; yh = (iy +1) %Ny;

      pudx = (u[xh][iy] + u[xh][iy] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc1);   
      pudy = (u[ix][yh] + u[ix][yl] - 2.0*u[ix][iy])/(calc2);    

    u_new[ix][iy] = 2.0*u[ix][iy] - u_old[ix][iy] + calc*(pudx+pudy);

  }
}
```

Comment: Also: calculations for `yl` and `yh` look like they could be hoisted out of the inner `for` loop, no?

Comment: Also: the term `2.0*u[ix][iy]` comes up three times and could be hoisted into a temp variable, I think.

Comment: @JVMATL : you are right. Corrected. And getting the invariants out of the loop is the next issue...

Comment: I hate questions like this.  Without a profiler and some hard numbers, one is only guessing if we are optimizing something that is busy work while doing a I/O xfer elsewhere that makes it all mute.

Comment: in the pudx temp, `u[xh][iy] + u[xh][iy]` is `2 * u[xh][iy]`.  Also agree this feels like a pre-calc early.

Comment: It is still a research question if using `for(ix=1;ix<Nx-1; ix++) {...}` (same for`y`) , and handling the edge cases separately would improve the locality of reference.